# What is the most efficient way to store images feature vector?

Tags: python, mysql, django, storage, feature-extraction

I'm working on project that needs to deal with images, I extract their feature vector instantly when any image uploaded then I store the feature vectors in `MySQL` database as text per each image.

Also I'm using `django` framework.

```
def search_images_by_features(query_image: ImageFieldFile, images):
    featured_images = [
        (calculate_similarity(load_features_from_str(image.features), get_image_feature(query_image)), image.item) for image in
        images if image.features is not None]
    ...
```

But looping on each image isn't a big deal as it takes more time as images increase.

Also my feature vector in database stored like that:
`0.0010601664,0.0003533888,0.8969008,0.0014135552,...`

---

Also is there a way to make MySQL database engine calculate similarity from feature vectors?

Comment: As a one image can have multiple features, this should be in a different table (aka class in Django) [django relationships can retrieve this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). Define similarity and maybe something can be done in mysql

Comment: Yeah I know,  I can extract features, well my function works well but its about time, I need to check all database images as soon as possible.. this function for about 100 image takes about 10-30 second which is too much for searching .. and if I have about 10000 image so its about to multiply time * 100

Comment: You function may work well, but it relies on all the image features being retrieved (or have I missed something in your code?). Sharing your feature comparison function and your table definition (with indexes) may provide some way of pushing part or all of the searching down to the database. Storing as text sounds wrong (as I assume you use numeric comparisons) as does storing in a comma list.

Comment: What is an image feature vector?

Comment: Well I use chi-square distance  for similarity it compares each vector
def calculate_similarity(features_a, features_b, eps=1e-10):
    return 0.5 * np.sum([((a - b) ** 2) / (a + b + eps)
                      for (a, b) in zip(features_a, features_b)])

Comment: Well feature vector is a list of numbers describes the image .. we use it to minify time instead of looping on each image pixel pixel.